# MacOS Pkg install fails with "Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=106"

Tags: macos, box

I encountered a problem with installing a signed package on MacOS, where the install failed on the summary panel with the message:

> The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to
> fail.

The logs, `Window > Installer Log` showed the error:

```
 Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=106 "The package “... .pkg” is missing or invalid." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/.../Box/.../Downloads/... .pkg, NSLocalizedDescription=The package “... .pkg” is missing or invalid.} {
        NSLocalizedDescription = "The package ... .pkg\U201d is missing or invalid.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that the reason for this error, was the the `.pkg` file had been put on a box sync folder, as ...

> Box Drive does not support Mac package files. If you attempt to upload
> a package file, you will receive the error "The Finder can't complete
> the operation because some data in the file can't be read or written
> (Error code -36)".

From https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043695774-Mac-Specific-Known-Issues-for-Box-Drive

Moving the `.pkg` to the desktop and installing from there did the trick.